# Angular 2 json getting data objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I got url which contains data arrays as json. I want to get and use all of the elements in it :

By doing this, i get everything and nothing specific. **For example : How to get data.name or data.price.... ?**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('this.url').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use array.find if you want to get the particular object name or price

```
 this.http.get('this.url').subscribe((data : any) => {
       let price = data.find(t=>t.name ==='yourName').price;
 });
```

if its just an Object, you could access using the property,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('this.url').subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data.name);
})
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer with modal + observable, would be awesome.

Comment: What do you mean by modal + observable?

Comment: Json url has multiple objects : {[name] [name] [name] [name] [name]}

Comment: Neither of the example works for me, i get only undefined.

Comment: can you post your JSON console.log(JSON.stringif(data));

Comment: copy and paste the text not the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174745/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-andrius-la).

Answer (score 0):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('this.url').subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data.name);

    })
```

try with any, or you can create a model and replace any with the model (which reflects the data you will recieve)

Answer (score -1):

If you are not able of doing `data.name` for example, then might be that your case is that `data` has a different structure and does not have the properties directly as children. You should be sure that `data` has the structure you're mentioning. In some cases there is another `data` property within, so you can test `data.data` and see what happens.